# Rails: Having issues redirecting after cropping image with Jcrop & paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, jcrop

I am trying to implement Jcrop for Paperclip and I am 99% done. I am able to crop the image and store it. The issue is that after the image is cropped and stored it again takes me to the Crop action with the recently cropped image. So it is asking me to crop a cropped image. I am not sure how to get out of it. I'd like to go to user_path after the image is cropped not crop again. Here is the code in my update action:

```
  def update
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if @user.avatar_file_name.nil?
      redirect_to :back
    else
      if params[:user].blank?
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
      else
        render :action => 'crop'
        @user.avatar.reprocess! if :cropping?
      end
    end
  end
```

If I have this instead, then the image won't crop. It is stored as the original image and I am redirected to the user_path:

```
  def update
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if @user.avatar_file_name.nil?
      redirect_to :back
    else
      if params[:user][:avatar].blank?
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
      else
        render :action => 'crop'
        @user.avatar.reprocess! if :cropping?
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you post your crop action?

Comment: Well there is no crop action. It is just a view. It is as per Ryan Bates railscast: [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast)

Comment: Ok, from my understanding, you should use the second version of your post. You always get the crop view because for some reason your params[:user][:avatar] is not getting blank after you crop. Can you see what is being posted after you press "crop"? There should not be a params[:user][:avatar] there.

Comment: This is what I get: `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Um2A5vAP2h9y9KXIl4TAGCAKUG93VahpkNwKryUoXfY=",
 "user"=>{"crop_x"=>"916",
 "crop_y"=>"497",
 "crop_w"=>"1140",
 "crop_h"=>"1140"},
 "commit"=>"Crop",
 "id"=>"JDLKWZF4eeIg5D"}`

Comment: Ok. Well: use the second part of your post, not your first. View the params of your request after you press the save button of your user. Your code expects a params[:user][:avatar]. Is it there?

Comment: You above comment is the params **after** user crops the image. What are the params you get **before** you render the crop action?

Comment: Sorry. `{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Um2A5vAP2h9y9KXIl4TAGCAKUG93VahpkNwKryUoXfY=",
 "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcacb8bfb08 @original_filename="DSCN0952.JPG",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"DSCN0952.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/p9/yzy1xtvj3g9_dpt_xhz0lqlh0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130516-78280-vgem8>>},
 "commit"=>"Upload Avatar",
 "id"=>"JDLKWZF4eeIg5D"}`

Comment: Do you use the first or the second version of your post?

Comment: The second currently. I see what you are saying. The issue is that it is rendering the crop view. If params[:user][:avatar].blank? was blank, it wouldn't render the crop view. The thing is it render and lets me crop. But once I hit crop it goes back to the user_path without cropping. Isn't that weird.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30072/discussion-between-grotori-and-pratski)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my question. It is probably very specific and won't ever help anyone, but here is the answer anyway. Thanks @grotori for your time!

```
  def update
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    if @user.avatar_file_name.nil?
      redirect_to :back
      elsif !params[:user][:crop_x].blank?
        @user.avatar.reprocess! 
        redirect_to edit_user_path(@user) and return
      else
        render :action => 'crop'
    end
  end
```